# TimePicker not call OnTimeChanged in API-21

Tags: android, android-timepicker

I use this code:

```
public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog {
private static final String TAG = CustomTimePickerDialog.class.getSimpleName();


public CustomTimePickerDialog(Context context, OnTimeSetListener listener, int hourOfDay, int minute, boolean is24HourView, String databaseTimeById) {
    super(context, listener, hourOfDay, minute, is24HourView);
}

@Override
public void onTimeChanged(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTimeChanged");
}
```

but `onTimeChanged` is not called **only** in API 21. What could be the problem? Or at least how to do it differently?

I tried extends `MyTimePickerDialog` from `AlertDialog` and setting custom view with TimePicker like this `setView(viewWithTimePicker)`, and then use the method  `timePicker.setOnTimeChanged(this)`. It working in API: 23, 22, 16 (!) but not in 21 (Android 5.0). Need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same issue with **Lolipop** so I added

**android:timePickerMode="spinner"** as timePickerMode and It worked.

```
<TimePicker
        android:id="@+id/timepick_start"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:timePickerMode="spinner"/>
```

Try this.

Comment: Yeah, it`s work. Wanted to do also, but stopped that on api>=21 i need  circle mode. As a quick solution is suitable, after, if I can find a different approach, complement the answer.
Thanks!

Comment: @whalemare Welcome :) and notify me when you find different approach Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to implements `TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener`

```
public class CustomTimePickerDialog extends TimePickerDialog implements TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener{
```

Comment: I don't need implement this listener. because in constuctor i send right (not null) instance of `OnTimeSetListener`. And i dont need override this method

Comment: And this method from docs: `Called when the user is done setting a new time and the dialog has
closed.`